# What does this nested for-loops compacted into a single line mean? - python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am reading some Python code, and have come across the following line that generates a two dimensional array.

```
self.slots = [[Slot(self.world,i,j) for j in range(NUMROWS)] for i in range(NUMCOLS)]
```

My questions are:

1) is this notation also known as a 'generator'?

2) how would you explain what this line means in english? i.e. "create an array of size `NUMROWS` `Slot` objects," etc.

3) what is the order of creation? is the `NUMROWS` array created first, and then the `NUMCOLS`?

Comment: This is called a list comprehension. It's related to, but not the same thing as, a generator/generator expression. (those are also two different but related things.) Look up "list comprehension," look at some examples, and this code will probably make sense.

Comment: A generator uses `()` instead of `[]`, and instead of creating the list, it iterates on the items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially,

```
[[Slot(self.world,i,j) for j in range(NUMROWS)] for i in range(NUMCOLS)]
```

is the same as:

```
slots = []
for i in range(NUMCOLS):
  column = []
  for j in range(NUMROWS):
    row = Slot(self.world, i, j)
    column.append(row)
  slots.append(column)
```

It's call a `list comprehension`, see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

For example:

```
>>> x, y = 2,3
>>> [[(i,j) for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)], [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]]
```